# How to interpret the subscript of this equation?

Tags: notation

In [this paper](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Emykland/paperlinks/Endogenous-S0266466613000418a.pdf) the authors in equation 18 present $\hat{\sigma_t^2}$ as
$$ \hat{\sigma}_{t}^2 = \frac{[X, X]_{t_{i M_n}} - [X, X]_{t_{(i-1)M_n}}}{t_{iM_n} - t_{(i-1)M_n}}. \tag{18} $$
How to read the subscript in both the numerator and denominator?
For example $[X, X]_{t_{(i-1)M_n}}$ is to be understood as iteration $(i-1)$ of block $M_n$?

Comment: Not sure 'pedix' is in English usage? (I cannot find it defined in several dictionaries or on Wikipedia.) If $X_{\text{pedix goes here}}$ is what you mean, I see notation in that position referred to as an 'index' (singular) or 'indices' (plural) in English.

Comment: yes you are right, I overestimated my English vocabulary

Comment: In Eq 18 the first term on the numerator differs from yours -- watch out for three levels of subscript in that term  (t is at the level of a subscript of [X,X], i and M are subscripts of t and n is a subscript of M). Please amend. (I will say the notation could probably be improved a bit)

Comment: @Glen_b yes it should now be updated correctly